# How to see more evaluation steps in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I want to see more evaluation steps in Tensorboard, while I'm training and evaluating my object detection (standard code in [tensorflow object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)).

[Here you can see what I mean for number of evaluation steps](https://media.giphy.com/media/fxQUlf9sTg6hdifFty/giphy.gif). As you can see, it's fixed to 10 visualization.

I can't find where to change and increase this parameter. Moreover, these visualizations are random and not the last 10.

Is it possible to set a different number of visualization?
And what can I do for see the last N evaluations instead of random N evaluations?

Thank you in advance.

---

Added: Image from link:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using this code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

(you should include that link to clarify in future questions, and if that assumption is wrong you should edit your question to specify what code you're using)

If you look at the `trainer.py` code at the bottom they have:

```
slim.learning.train(
    train_tensor,
    logdir=train_dir,
    master=master,
    is_chief=is_chief,
    session_config=session_config,
    startup_delay_steps=train_config.startup_delay_steps,
    init_fn=init_fn,
    summary_op=summary_op,
    number_of_steps=(
        train_config.num_steps if train_config.num_steps else None),
    save_summaries_secs=120,
    sync_optimizer=sync_optimizer,
    saver=saver)
```

It looks like they've hard coded `save_summaries_sec=120` to save a summary every 120 seconds. That's what you want to edit to change the tensorboard summary update period.

---

Edit: I've added the image to the question to help clarify. I believe the answer is in `tf.summary.image` you have a property `max_outputs` which controls the number of values from the block of images. To choose a subset of images specifically you should simply write your own code to select them in whatever way you see fit, randomly, or in some order, then pass that new set of images to `tf.summary.image`.

Comment: Yes I used this code, I edit my question, I hope now is more clear. However, i don't think it's the right parameter... i changed it to 600, and nothing happens. What i want is to visualize more than 10 evaluation in tensorboard, and not the last 10 random evaluation. Or, if it's not possible, to see the last 10 evaluations.

Comment: Tensorboard will show you any number of evaluations. This says that you want a data point computed and stored in tensorboard every 120 seconds (or 600 seconds). If you set this to every 10 seconds you should see quite a lot of data points.  I'm not sure where you get the number 10 from, it doesn't ring a bell to me. And I don't understand what you mean by random N evaluations. Are you perhaps having an issue with only computing a single batch? If so `tf.metrics` has methods of aggregating measurements over multiple batches.

Comment: I'm talking about this https://media.giphy.com/media/fxQUlf9sTg6hdifFty/giphy.gif . Here you can see 10 evaluation, random, i wish to see more evaluation, or the last 10, not random 10...

Comment: I've added some detail to my question and added the image to your question. I'm not 100% sure I've nailed it on the head yet though, might need some experimentation.

Comment: I can't find max_outputs property. Where is it? If I add it in eval_util.py line 182:

  summary = tf.Summary(value=[
      tf.Summary.Value(
          tag=tag,
          image=tf.Summary.Image(max_outputs=20,
              encoded_image_string=vis_utils.encode_image_array_as_png_str(
                  image)))
  ])

It gave me this error... Protocol message Image has no "max_outputs" field.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider looking at the `eval_config` section of the model config file.

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 100
  num_visualizations: 50
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  #max_evals: 10
}
```

I'm guessing that `max_evals` is what you're looking for.

Comment: No. I'm not talking about the evaluations limit. I'm talking about this https://media.giphy.com/media/fxQUlf9sTg6hdifFty/giphy.gif . Here you can see 10 evaluation, random, i wish to see more evaluation, or the last 10, not random 10...